# Why do different strings have the same ID in Python?

Tags: python

It is stated that strings are immutable objects, and when we make changes in that variable it actually creates a new string object.

So I wanted to test this phenomenon with this piece of code:

```
result_str = ""

print("string 1 (unedited):", id(result_str))

for a in range(1,11):
    result_str = result_str + str(a)
    print(f"string {a+1}:", id(result_str))
```

And I got the following IDs:

```
string 1 (unedited): 2386354993840
string 2: 2386357170336
string 3: 2386357170336
string 4: 2386357170336
string 5: 2386357170336
string 6: 2386357170336
string 7: 2386357170336
string 8: 2386357170336
string 9: 2386360410800
string 10: 2386360410800
string 11: 2386360410800
```

So, if each string is different from each other, then why do the strings 2-8 and 9-11 have the same ID? And, if somehow this question is explained why does the ID change at string 9 specifically?

Comment: I don't know at what point the old and new `result_str` are destroyed and created and if they overlap in their lifetime, but the Python docs says "Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value."

Comment: why it changes at 9 is machine dependent, in my computer all the values have the same id. My guess is python allocates the memory to original string, then when that string is deleted that id is emptied and ready to use. Since it's first in the stack, it gets assigned to the next variable. but sometime it uses some other memory location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you associate with `result_str` create reaches end of lifetime at the next assignment. Hence the possibility of duplicate id.

Here's the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is
>   guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its
>   lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same
>   id() value.

Comment: This makes sense. Additionally, why do you it does not use the same id going from string 8 to 9? Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. Why do you care?

Comment: I was just curious whether there was a specific answer.

Comment: The id changes when the size (obtained with `os.getsizeof(result_str)`) of the string exceeds certain sizes. These sizes are deterministic (at least seem to be from basic experimentation), but machine dependant as @osman-mamun said.